# what attribute for protobuf-net for DbGeography type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, protobuf-net

I've been reading the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Attributes) for protobuf-net attributes, but i'm not well-versed with protobuf specifications.

I'm using it in a MVC project and during de-serialization, the DbGeography is empty.

### Class

```
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    [ProtoMember(2, AsReference = true)]
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
}
```

This is what my class looks like currently, i've tried using `DynamicType` & `IsRequired`, anyway all didn't work. Rather than trying to guess/mix & match, i'm hoping that someone has been doing something similar.

The nearest thing i've seen while looking around is this project that have a custom [reader](https://code.google.com/p/spatiallite-net/source/browse/src/SpatialLite.Osm/IO/PbfReader.cs) and [writer](https://code.google.com/p/spatiallite-net/source/browse/src/SpatialLite.Osm/IO/PbfWriter.cs) that uses protobuf for spatial data types, but it's a custom class.

### Update

```
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    [ProtoMember(2, DynamicType= true)] //<-- this works
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
}
```

But i'm still wondering what's the best way to label these members, like a performance vs size trade-off

### Update 2

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2, AsReference = true)] 
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(8, AsReference = true)] //<-- What is the cost of using this for List<Bar>? since im using a non-primitive type
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re the update:

```
[ProtoMember(2, DynamicType= true)] //<-- this works
```

I do **not** advise that. As for the *correct* thing to do; I would recommend a surrogate type:

```
[ProtoContract]
sealed class DbGeographyPoco
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator DbGeographyPoco(DbGeography value)
    {
        return value == null ? null : new DbGeographyPoco {
            Value = value.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText };
    }
    public static implicit operator DbGeography(DbGeographyPoco value)
    {
        return value == null ? null : DbGeography.FromText(value.Value);
    }
}
```

which you can then register somewhere during app startup via:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(DbGeography),false)
   .SetSurrogate(typeof(DbGeographyPoco));
```

Comment: So I should leave the original class as is and remove the dynamictype = true? Will there be any downstream effect?

Comment: @LeeGary define "downstream effect"? It won't be compatible with the `DynamicType` serialization, but it might *work*, which is always nice. Note that the implementation shown is merely illustrative - I don't use `DbGeography` much myself so it is from memory. The point is: rather than try to serialize something bespoke, complex and outside of our control: change it to something simple and *inside* of our control

Comment: downstream effect as in, since we are altering the runtimetypemodel. will it affect other parts of the code that uses DbGeography? and i've updated the question slightly to include a List<Bar> member, which i used AsReference=True, is this the way to go as well?

Comment: @LeeGary I'm sorry your edit was blocked; it was fine; the reviewers need to feel ashamed

Comment: @LeeGary I would *tend* to avoid `AsReference` usage unless there's a good reason - what are you trying to do there? is it commonly-repeated geography?

Comment: Nope it's just a list of my class, is it best to leave the member attribute untouched unless I really know what each attribute does? I'm still getting rather good performance as my objects aren't very big or complex